# DB2 Table Partitioning

Tags: db2, partitioning, db2-luw

DB2 LUW V11.1
Unix 12 operating system

1) When creating a partition, do the partitioning columns need to be not null?

2) Let's say you partition on a column defined as a date which is nullable. There are four partitions a row could be assigned. If an inserted row is null, which partition does the row get inserted?

Any insight would be gratefully appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) answers your questions, for range partitioning (as distinct from hash partitioning).

The range-partitioning column can be nullable.

When adding a new partition (with [ALTER TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html) .... ADD PARTITION ...) you will use constant values for the STARTING FROM and ENDING AT clauses.

The handling of null depends on whether you specify NULLS FIRST or NULLS LAST on the partitioning expression, which evaluate to minvalue or maxvalue respectively.